# Which online Code Editor / IDE / Playground has SVELTE support?

Tags: ide, editor, svelte

Are there alternatives to these options

- the official Svelte [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.0)
- [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)
- Stackblitz [Vite&Svelte](https://vite.new/svelte) / [Vite&Svelte TS](https://vite.new/svelte-ts) (thanks @dummdidumm)

to code Svelte in the browser?

(I don't consider this a 'opinion-based' question, which I know should be avoided... if this question still conflicts with the forum rules in any other way, please let me know in the comments, thanks)

Comment: Have a look at StackBlitz. It has support for Svelte. I did not use it myself.

Comment: I had and it seems to have supported Svelte2, but unfortunately not Svelte3 (anymore, not yet..?) Couldn't find answers on that, but thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

Stackblitz recently introduced support for Vite templates, among them are two for Svelte:

- Svelte: https://vite.new/svelte
- Svelte + TS: https://vite.new/svelte-ts

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot!